# Installing already existing laravel application with private packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail, private-repository

One of my teammates created a Laravel application which uses a few private packages and also uses laravel sail. The composer.json file contains this:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "URL TO SATIS PRIVATE REPOS HERE"
        }
    ],
```

According to [laravel sail documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects), the way to install dependencies on an already existing application is this:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

However, when i run it it fails when it tries to install the first private package and shows the following message:

`Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'git@bitbucket.org:PACKAGENAME' '/.composer/cache/vcs/git-bitbucket.org-org:PACKAGENAME'`

`fatal: could not create leading directories of '/.composer/cache/vcs/git-bi tbucket.org-PACKAGENAME'`

My teammate told me that when he was installing the packages (via `sail composer require privatepackagename`) it was asked for auth details and in my case is not asking for anything.

If tried to pass my ssh keys to the command but no success:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -v "/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa:/home/sail/.ssh/id_rsa" \
    -v "/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:/home/sail/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My docker skills are not great, but I usually try to make the container runnable( so it doesn't quit/crash) and then check the docker environment internally via terminal. Maybe you have the wrong key location or even the wrong key copied(been there done that). I use the command `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash` to get into container and start my inversigation by running commands like `su -s /bin/bash <git user>` and then `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. I'm not sure if it will help you, but I hope it will :)